# Getting list of conflicting files after failed TFS check-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've made a custom tool that is going to check in a list of files into a TFS team project. What I'm trying to do is trying to check in the files. If there is an issue, I'm trying to output the files that are causing the issue. The causes could be that there is a pending change on the file where another user is holding a lock on the item. Another cause could be another user having checked in the same server item with changes.

So basically,

workspace.CheckIn(PendingChanges);

if (failed)
    List changes = new List();
.
.
.

What should I do?

Comment: `What should I do?` You should try the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation of Workspace.CheckIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732574%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it will either return 0 or a negative integer or throw an exception. The exceptions thrown for "normal" check-in issues are [CheckinException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.checkinexception.aspx) and [VersionControlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolexception.aspx).

```
int changesetId = 0;
try {
    changesetId = workspace.CheckIn(PendingChanges);
} catch(CheckinException exception) {
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    return;
} catch(VersionControlException exception) {
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    return;
}

if(changesetId <= 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Unknown CheckIn error. Changeset id 0 returned");
    return;
}
```